# how to overcome a parsing error in SSCANF function in Clanguage?

Tags: c, string, string-parsing

how to parse a empty substring with sscanf.......
if my string str[]="is first,,third,final." i cannot able to read the third and final substring if my second substring is zero. Is there an solution to overcome this error.....?????

```
**Code:**


#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *tokenstring = "first,second,25.5,15";
int result, i;
double fp;
char o[10], f[10], s[10], t[10];

void main()
{
   result = sscanf(tokenstring,"%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%s", o,t,s,f);`sscanf function`
   fp = atof(s);
   i   = atoi(f);
   printf("%s\n %lf\n %s\n %d\n", o,t,fp,i);
}
for this program if i execute my output is 

`output`
>first
>second
>25.5
>15
```

but if i try to remove the substring "second" in the tokenstring pointer... and if i try to execute, then i get output as:

```
char *tokenstring = "first,,25.5,15";

>first
>(blank)
>0.00
>0
```

how do i read the third and fourth substring in the string"tokenstring"...any suggestions ?????????? .

Comment: if your `sscanf` returned less than 4 you cannot reliably access `f`; if it returned less than 3 you cannot reliably access `s`. Check `sscanf`'s return value!

Answer (score 0):

Parse the input character-by-character

```
char part[4][1000] = {0};
const char *input = "first,,25.5,15";
size_t k, n;

for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
    char *curr = part[k];
    while (*input && *input != ',') {
        *curr++ = *input++;
    }
    if (*input == ',') input++; else break;
}
/* (k+1) elements have been parsed */
for (n = 0; n < k + 1; n++) {
    printf("part %d (between square parenthesis): [%s]\n", (int)n, part[n]);
}
```

Comment: hi when i try to execute it this code, for me the value in the curr pointer is zero at all times........

Comment: After the code runs, the parts are in the array `part`. I've updated the code to show that.

Comment: hey buddy, i got this code working but i m not clearly understanding where u r assigning the value of the pointer named "curr" to array named "part"........because in your code, in the 6th line you r assigning the value of array "part" in to the pointer "Curr"......then how the pointer "Curr" will periodically updates the value of that array"part".......

Comment: In my code `part[k]` is itself an array (of 1000 characters). It is that array (there are 4 of them in total), decayed to a pointer to its first element, that I assign to `curr`. The first element of `part[1]` is `part[1][0]`. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/) to better understand the similiraties and differences between arrays and pointers.

Comment: i actually want to tokenize the string of "GPRMC,225446,A,4916.45,N,12311.12,W,000.5,054.7,191194,020.3,E*68" using some function.....and save each part of substring into different fields of same structure.....but i dont think 2D array would be an suitable option for this to do....... do u have any other idea to implement

Comment: **No guesses!** I've hard coded a size of `1000`. Real code should check for overflow. The number of elements of an array can be obtained with `sizeof array / sizeof *array`. If what you have is a pointer, there is no way to know the size of the underlying arrays: when you convert the array to pointer, get the number of elements and pass that around too.

Comment: Do a function to copy the `nth` element of the string to a buffer. Then `strcpy` or `strtol` that buffer to the proper struct member. If you find this is too slow (finding `','` over and over again) you can try a faster, more complicated, approach.